# Automated testing of bare metal C code (microprocessor firmware): simulating changes in hardware registers

Tags: c, multithreading, automated-tests, cross-compiling

I want to write automated tests for some very low level C code on a PC that I will port to the microprocessor. I understand that there will be differences (implementation-specific behaviours such as size of int), which I will have to live with.

I need ideas on how to simulate changes of volatile variables (which map to special function registers in the microcontroller). E.g. in the code below, the value of the register flag `TX_BUFF_FULL` can repeatedly change during the course of the execution of the code, when space in the transmit buffer becomes available or is used up:

```
void send_str(char * str){
    // for each non-null character
    for (char i = 0; str[i]; i++){
        // wait for space in TX hardware buffer
        while(TX_BUFF_FULL);
        // put character into hardware FIFO
        TX_REGISTER = str[i];
    }
}
```

`TX_BUFF_FULL` and `TX_REGISTER` are volatile variables mapped to the address of special function registers for the UART.

Ideally I will write the source so that it can be compiled without changes for both the automated tests on a PC and running on the microcontroller, which probably needs preprocessor directives.

For example, a directive that uses this line when compiled for the microcontroller:

```
while(TX_BUFF_FULL);
```

but uses this when compiled for testing on the PC:

```
while(test_tx_buff_full());
```

where the `test_tx_buff_full()` function would be a part of the test suite that emulates changes in the state of the registers. I can't think of a different way of achieving the result.

Is this a reasonable way? What would be a neat way of implementing the preprocessor directives to achieve this? Is there a neater way? Thanks

Edit: From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115115/test-automation-with-embedded-hardware?rq=1), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451984/testing-firmware) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958841/unit-testing-patterns-for-microcontroller-c-code), some other ideas are:

- using preprocessor macros that produce inline code to replace reading of registers
- using a programmable hardware test bench that can bootload and perform unit and integration tests, bypassing the need for a simulator

Comment: You say "I can't think of a different way of achieving the result" but then there's the [tag:multithreading] tag. That is likely to be a far more robust solution, by the way, than the preprocessor.

Comment: What embedded processor is it, by the way? There might just be a simulator available.

Comment: Given the nature of multithreading, I can't see how timing could be of stimuli could be controlled since the OS is in charge of scheduling. It's for the PIC 8-bit microcontrollers - the MPLAB IDE has a simulator but is not only buggy but cannot be run from CLI and is simply not built for automated tests. To make things worse still, the stimuli control language is undocumented and not officially supported

Comment: The best that could be said is that timing wouldn't be *too* deterministic, which is another simulation pitfall. As for bugs, you are essentially proposing to design a competing product. You really need a simulator for this application. Perhaps there is another one on the market? I have to go now, good luck…

Comment: Would you consider a testing framework based on C++?  Your embedded source would remain C, but the test framework used to execute the tests on the host would be C++.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that this could be done using the kind of APIs used to implement breakpoint debugging. On linux, this could be [ptrace](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace) (in particular, the `PTRACE_POKEDATA` operation could be used to deliver the new volatile value, and `PTRACE_SINGLESTEP` would allow for precisely timing its delivery). I'm certain that analogs exist on Windows and BSD, but I am less familiar with those platforms.